Why is Django Adding LIMIT 21 on get_object_or_404
Model
class Entity(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    # required fields for registration
    owner_password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    email_id_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_no_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registered_business = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner_id_details = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    registration_details = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

View
This is the get api for getting entity detail.
class EntityDetailView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        entity = get_object_or_404(Entity, uuid=id)
        serializer = EntitySerializer(entity)
        return Response(serializer.data)

Resulting SQL query
SELECT "entities_entity"."id",
       "entities_entity"."uuid",
       "entities_entity"."institute_name",
       "entities_entity"."owner_name",
       "entities_entity"."contact_no",
       "entities_entity"."email_id",
       "entities_entity"."owner_password",
       "entities_entity"."address",
       "entities_entity"."email_id_verified",
       "entities_entity"."phone_no_verified",
       "entities_entity"."registered_business",
       "entities_entity"."owner_id_details",
       "entities_entity"."registration_details",
       "entities_entity"."is_active",
       "entities_entity"."created_at",
       "entities_entity"."updated_at"
  FROM "entities_entity"
 WHERE "entities_entity"."uuid" = '68e0956b-c166-4844-8842-51371c385a90'::uuid
 LIMIT 21

Why is Django adding limit 21 in my resulting SQL Query
I tested it using Django debug toolbar.

that is strange... are you sure that's the get_object_or_404 query and not from some other place in the code?

Did you update Django?

@Anentropic Yes, i am sure of it

@toyotaSupra Yes, i am using Django==4.2.2 version

The latest Django is 5.x.x

You ask about solution of Django's famous GET problem, which was solved with this monkeypatch "limit 21".
In Django till 3.0 in method queryset.get you can find following code:
1     def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
2         """
3         Performs the query and returns a single object matching the given
4         keyword arguments.
5         """
6         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
7         if self.query.can_filter():
8             clone = clone.order_by()
9         num = len(clone)
10        if num == 1:
11            return clone._result_cache[0]
12        if not num:
13            raise self.model.DoesNotExist("%s matching query does not exist."
14                    % self.model._meta.object_name)
15        raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned("get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s! Lookup parameters were %s"
16                % (self.model._meta.object_name, num, kwargs))

What happens here:
If you have 1.000.000 rows, and you want to get only one object, but you write wrong query selector, on line 6 you can create queryset, which asks ALL rows. for example:
# args=()
# kwargs={}
6         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

After that, on line 9 you get ALL objects from database. Usally it can kill whole server:
9        num = len(clone)

Why it is, in few words - len really fetch data from database in memory. It is wery well described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated
After Django 3.0 the method queryset.get was changed:
1  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
2         clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
3         if self.query.can_filter() and not self.query.distinct_fields:
4             clone = clone.order_by()
5         limit = None
6         if not clone.query.select_for_update or connections[clone.db].features.supports_select_for_update_with_limit:
7             limit = MAX_GET_RESULTS
8             clone.query.set_limits(high=limit)
9         num = len(clone)
10        if num == 1:
11            return clone._result_cache[0]
12        if not num:
13            raise self.model.DoesNotExist()
14        raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned()

This works better, because in the worst case you only get MAX_GET_RESULTS=21 objects and no more.
But this is the wrong solution IMHO, because it still contains a logical error. I think the limit should be set to 2, not more, because 2 or 22 or 222 doesn't matter here, line 14 throws an error without information about the received data.
Also, I think it's better to raise the error on line 14, but add the received multiple objects in the context of the error - this will help to reduce the number of database hits, for example, if I want to find which objects were the cause of the error.
And why exactly 21? Developers got lazy, instead of creating a new constant, they just use the existing MAX_GET_RESULTS constant, which is usually used to organize data pagination when reading the database.
Discussed here: https://github.com/django/django/pull/11215#issuecomment-483629741

What an awesome response! And I mean that in all honesty.

@mawimawi, thank you.
